# How can I make my function to run the moment the page is running?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload, transition

I would like to make a function run the moment a person loads my page. No interactivity. The function is loading when someone clicks. I also would like to make the function loop after 1 minute and a half. I tried replacing "click" for window.onload and body.onload but as you may have noticed by now I am a true begginer with javascript. Can someone give me a hand please. For now all I have is this:

```js
// Animate an element by adding a class to it:
// Paramaters: 
// anim: the class name to add
// time: animation duration (optional, fallsback to the class)
// cb: an optional callback function to happen once the animation ends
$.fn.animatecss = function(anim, time, cb) {

    if (time) this.css('-webkit-transition', time / 1000 + 's');
    this.addClass(anim);

    if ($.isFunction(cb)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Ensure that the element is available inside the callback.
            $(this).each(cb);
        }, (time) ? time : 5000);
    }

    return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box')click(function() {
        $(this).animatecss('blur-out', 5000, function() {
            console.log('callback');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.blur-out {
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease-out;
    transition: all 5s ease-out;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.box {    
    background:#fff;  
    margin: 80px; 
   padding: 20px;    
    
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://companionplants.com/images/small-plant2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: You mean this part here: $('.box')click(function() {


        $(this).animatecss('blur-out', 5000, function() {

            console.log('callback');

        });


    });

Comment: Yes.  That's a good start as what you have now is a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').click(function() {
        $(this).animatecss('blur-out', 5000, function() {
            console.log('callback');
        });
    });

    // add this line
    $('.box').trigger('click');
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to loop this behaviour. Forcing the animation to start again after 1'30''. I know it's asking for too much but would you be so kind to help me with that one?

Comment: Yes, give me a min :)

Comment: Here is a pure CSS example. This is better because it doesn't rely on JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/gmwyygsr/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, You want to start animation automatically after page is loaded.

Remove event handler for click. Leave code for animation like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
        
  $('.box').animatecss('blur-out', 5000, function() {
    
    console.log('callback');
    
  });

            
});
```

For automatically repeating this code, you need to place this code in recursive function with settimeout().

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  function animate(){
    $('.box').animatecss('blur-out', 5000, function() {
      
      console.log('callback');

    });
            
    setTimeout( animate(), 60000);
  }
  
  animate();
            
});
```

I hope that there are no errors, I cann't check it now, but I think it will help you